# How do I inherit from different templates in Djanog based on whether the user is logged in or not

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

Exactly what the question says. I have three templates `base.html`, `logged_in_base.html`, and `page.html`. I want `page.html` to extend `base.html` when the user isn't logged in and to extend `logged_in_base.html` when the user is logged in. How do I do this?

(This is basically because I have a different navbar for logged in users and not logged in users.)

Answer (score 1):

Since `{% extends %}` needs to be the first statement in a template, one cannot put the logic in the template.

But one can put the logic in the view since `{% extends %}` can work with a variable:

**views.py**

```
def page(request):
    base_template = 'logged_in_base.html' if request.user.is_authenticated else 'base.html'
    return render(request, 'page.html',
                  {'base_template': base_template})
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends base_template %}
<!-- Now put your content here -->
```

---

An alternative solution could be a single base template and conditional statement to decide which navigation bar to use.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- Navbar Logged in -->
{% else %}
    <!-- Navbar anonymous user -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without touching the views? I'm trying to override allauth library templates and don't want to be modifying all the views.

Comment: @ratchek You could simply use a single `base.html` template and use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}<!-- Navbar Logged in -->{% else %}<!-- Navbar anonymous user -->{% endif %}`

Comment: You're right! I totally blanked on that. Thank you! (I'm not sure on Stackoverflow etiquette. Should I accept the answer above even though it didn't really fix my issues? Or should I wait till you type this up? I feel unsure about what to do because it's my fault - I didn't give enough information in my initial post)